# How to fix the code which replacing original value of list with other possible value?

Tags: java, list

I wrote a function to generate a new set of list of boolean from given boolean list. When I exit the code, it changes the value of my original list.

I tried to print my original list after every operation. It changes the original value after the following code in the function called 'synthesizeChild'.

```java
for (Map.Entry < Double, List < Integer >> entry: finalID.entrySet()) {
    if (decode.equals(entry.getKey())) {
        chromosome.setId(entry.getValue().get(LOCAL_RANDOM.nextInt(entry.getValue().size())));
    }
}
```

These are the functions related to the synthesizeChild function.

```java
public static Population synthesizeChild(final Population parentArg) {
    List < Chromosome > tempChr = new ArrayList < >();
    for (int i = 0; i < parentArg.getPopulace().size(); i++) {
        tempChr.add(parentArg.getPopulace().get(i));
    }
    //        tempChr.addAll(parentArg.getPopulace());

    Population tempparent = new Population(tempChr);

    Population child = new Population();
    List < Chromosome > populace = new ArrayList < >();
    Map < Double,
    List < Integer >> finalID = maplookupID();
    /**
         * child chromosomes undergo crossover and mutation.
         * the child chromosomes are selected using binary tournament selection.
         * crossover returns an array of exactly two child chromosomes synthesized from two parent
         * chromosomes.
         */
    while (populace.size() < Configuration.getPopulationSize())
    for (Chromosome chromosome: crossover(binaryTournamentSelection(new Population(tempparent.getPopulace())), binaryTournamentSelection(new Population(tempparent.getPopulace())))) {
        chromosome = (mutation(chromosome));

        if (!penalityFunction(chromosome)) {
            continue;
        }

        Double decode = decodeGeneticCode(chromosome.getGeneticCode());

        for (Map.Entry < Double, List < Integer >> entry: finalID.entrySet()) {
            if (decode.equals(entry.getKey())) chromosome.setId(entry.getValue().get(LOCAL_RANDOM.nextInt(entry.getValue().size())));
        }

        if (!isDuplicate(tempparent, chromosome)) {
            populace.add(chromosome);
        }

    }

    child.setPopulace(populace);

    return child;
}

public static boolean isDuplicate(final Population parentList, final Chromosome chromosome) {
    for (int j = 0; j < parentList.getPopulace().size(); j++) {
        if (parentList.getPopulace().get(j).getId() == (chromosome.getId())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static Map < Double,
List < Integer >> maplookupID() {
    Map < Integer,
    Double > maplookupid = lookupfoID();
    Map < Double,
    List < Integer >> finalID = new HashMap < >();
    Set < Double > decimalValues = new HashSet < >();
    for (Map.Entry < Integer, Double > entry: maplookupid.entrySet()) {
        decimalValues.add(entry.getValue());
    }
    for (Double decimal: decimalValues) {
        {
            List < Integer > listofID = new ArrayList < >();
            for (Map.Entry < Integer, Double > entry: maplookupid.entrySet()) {
                if (decimal.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                    listofID.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
            finalID.put(decimal, listofID);
        }

    }
    return finalID;
}

public static double decodeGeneticCode(final Allele[] geneticCode) {

    double value = 0;
    String binaryString = "";

    for (Allele bit: geneticCode) binaryString += bit.getGene() ? "1": "0";
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryString.length(); i++) if (binaryString.charAt(i) == '1') value += Math.pow(2, binaryString.length() - 1 - i);

    return value;
}
```

The original value of parentArg should not change. But it is changing. Can anyone fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with Object references, not with Object values. When you populate the List tempChr with Chromosomes you load the Chromosome references and not the content of the Chromosomes. Therefore if you change the content of a Chromosome you've changed the CONTENT of parentArg. Either you "clone" the parentArg Chromosomes before you populate tempChr and manipulate them or you create new Chromosomes with the copy of the parentArg Chromosomes and manipulate the new created Chromosomes. Only so the Chromosomes of parentArg stay unchanged.

Comment: I am using new chromosome list named tempChr to copy entire values from parentArg.  What is the other way to clone it?

Comment: using the interface Clonable as following:

public class Chromosome implements Cloneable {
  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{  
    return super.clone();  
  }
  // your codes
}